# Can't install Scipy with pip

Tags: python, scipy, pip

I am trying to install Scipy, but when I run

```
pip install scipy
```

I get this long and ugly message, and I am totally clueless about what it means:

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.0.zip
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\USER\\Ap
pData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-2bwzfzez\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().repla
ce('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
1tn4ljy2-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-whe
els\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
      pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2bwzfzez\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2bwzfzez\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2bwzfzez\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```

I have tried to update pip, as suggested in other similar questions, but it says that it is already up to date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to install it from the wheel package? You can find the packages here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Installation (for example):

```
pip install scipy‑0.19.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
```

According to the error stack, you might need the python 3.6 version (cp36). Don't forget you need to install [numpy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) as well.